# AIC vs BIC vs MDL

Tags: r, time-series, data-mining, aic, bic

I am trying to learn the difference between the three approaches and their applications.

a) As I understand,

```
AIC = -LL+K 

BIC = -LL+(K*logN)/2
```

Unless I am missing something, shouldn't the K that minimizes the AIC minimize BIC as well since N is constant.

I looked at this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577/is-there-any-reason-to-prefer-the-aic-or-bic-over-the-other/767#767) but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

b) According to Witten's book on Data Mining (pg 267) the definition of MDL for evaluating the quality of network is the same as BIC. Is there a difference between BIC and MDL?

c) What are the different approaches to compute MDL? I am looking for its application in Clustering, Time Series Analysis (ARIMA and Regime Switching) and Attribute Selection. While almost all commonly used packages in R report AIC and BIC, I couldn't find any that implements MDL and I wanted to see if I can write it myself.

Thank you.

Comment: (1) What you seem to be missing is that when you change $K$, you change $LL$.  (2) What do you mean by "MDL"?

Comment: @whuber: probably minimum description length. Also, $N$ is not a constant (in the sense that say $\pi$ is)...for some dataset $N$ will not be large *enough*.

Comment: @whuber: wouldn't LL and K be same for both AIC and BIC user603: I mean N is constant for a given dataset. The relationship between AIC and BIC seems to be that AIC = BIC + K*(1-c) where c = (logN)/2.

Comment: For a particular model, LL will be the same for AIC and BIC; but their use is to compare models. Since they impose different penalties, they sometimes (not that often, in my experience) give different results.

Comment: When comparing two values of AIC for two values of $K$, you are looking at $LL_0 - LL_1 - K_0 + K_1$. When comparing two values of $BIC$ you are looking at $LL_0 - LL_1 - \log(N)(K_0 - K_1)/2$. Thus the two will not necessarily be optimal for the same values of $K$.

Answer (score 1):

MDL and BIC are sometimes confused to be the same model order estimator, but that is not the case. MDL is derived from BIC under two major assumptions. One is that the number of samples tend to infinity, and the second is the the samples are i.i.d.

see my derivation here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/246611/95551