# For what kind of model do the minimum description length (MDL) and the Bayesian information criterion (BIC) give the same estimation?

Tags: bayesian, dimensionality-reduction

It is known that BIC=-MDL in many cases. For what kind of ,model the number of dimension is same and for what kind of model they differ?

Comment: I recently read a detailed answer for this [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/246611).